# xml one record per line in c++

Tags: c++, xml

I am writing a large xml file in C++. What i need is the capability to construct dom trees of records in chunks and flush the chunks to disk. So for example,

```
-----------chunk create-----
<record>data<record>
<record>data<record>
<record>data<record>
<record>data<record>
-----------chunk flush--------
```

Also, a single line should contain one full record as shown above. what i dont want is printing in format shown below

```
<record>
 data
</record>
```

Which library would allow both the above functionality?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663).

Comment: @ildjarn this question is not a `call for a recommendation` in the sense that it does not ask for `what is the best` to quote you metalink... the question asks for site members to draw on their experience to suggest which library has a specific functionality as to the formatting of xml output... the question may be niche, but by no means is it subjective or debate provoking...

Comment: @Jimm what all xml libraries have you tried so far... also what platform are u running on...

Comment: @user1055604 : [Stack Overflow is also not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/166663), so either way.

Comment: :) ... i guess your right... lets hope @Jimm tries some of the suggestions here and elsewhere on the site and comes back with a solid question...

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try TinyXML : http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/

Answer (score 0):

i use [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).